# Задание значения модели в mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Не получается задать значение полям модели в MVC asp.net. 
 Класс модели:

```
public class PropertyInformation
{
    [Display(Name = "Property Name:")]
    public string   PropertyName { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public string   Street { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "City/State/")]
    public string   City { get; set; }
  }
```

Класс контроллера:

```
 public class MainController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(PropertyInformation pi)
    {
        return PartialView("Underwriting", pi);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Post(PropertyInformation pi)
    {
        return View("ValidationSuccess", pi);
    }
}
```

Представление в котором задаются данные:

```
  @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Underwriting";
    }

   <h2>Underwriting</h2>

    <div>@Html.Partial("PropertyInfoView")</div>
    <div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Post", "Main", FormMethod.Post))
    {
       @*кнопочка с фреймворка deevexpress*@
        @Html.DevExpress().Button(settings =>
     {
       settings.Name = "Add";
       settings.UseSubmitBehavior = true;
   }).GetHtml()
  }
 </div>
```

PartialView представления:

```
    @model Calculator.v0._0._3.Models.PropertyInformation

@using (Html.BeginForm("Post", "Main", FormMethod.Post))
{

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>PropertyInformation</h4>
        <hr />
        <p>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.PropertyName, "Название")
            <br />
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.PropertyName)
        </p>

        <p>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Street, "улица")
            <br />
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Street)
        </p>
    </div>
}
```

представление финального результата (проверяю то что все работает)

```
  @model Calculator.v0._0._3.Models.PropertyInformation
  @{
    ViewBag.Title = "ValidationSuccess";
  }

  <h2>ValidationSuccess</h2>
  <div>
    <label>Name :</label>
    <br />
   @Html.DevExpress().LabelFor(m => m.PropertyName, settings =>
   {
    settings.Text = Model.PropertyName;
   }).GetHtml()
  </div>
```

Надо чтоб задавалось значение модели, чего не происходит

В представлении `ValidationSuccess` не отображается имя, просто `Name :` и все. 
 что не верно и где исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте, присвоили ли вы свойству PropertyName класса PropertyInformation значение в контроллере (или где-либо ещё).